# Call not working properly to call function in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

Im kinda new to assembly, so im trying to create a ticket buying system which has 4 function. User can enter 1 to 4 to select the function but when i enter 4 to the run reset function it run view_comp function (which is the 3rd function). The other 3 function works properly but only 4th function has problem

```
.model small
.stack 150h
.data
Menu db 10, 13, 'Enter a choice (1 to 2):'
db 10, 13, '1) Enter 1 to view activites'
db 10, 13, '2) Enter 2 to view workshop'
db 10, 13, '3) Enter 3 to view competition'
db 10, 13, '4) Reset value', 10, 13, '$'


msg db 10,13, "activities $10"
msg2 db 10,13, "workshop $15"
msg3 db 10,13, "view competition $20"
Fdigit db 0
Sdigit db 0

result db 10,13,"sum= : $"
afd db '1'
asd db '0'
wfd db '1'
wsd db '5'
cfd db '2'
csd db '0'


.code

Main proc


mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

DisplayMenu:
mov dx,OFFSET Menu
mov ah,9
int 21h
mov ah,1
int 21h


cmp al, '1'
je view_activites 
cmp al, '2'
je view_workshop
cmp al, '3' 
call view_comp
cmp al, '4'
call reset 



view_activites:
; code to view activites
mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset msg
int 21h

mov bl,Sdigit 
sub bl,30h
mov cl,asd

add bl,cl

mov al,bl
mov ah,00h
aaa

mov cl,al
mov bl,ah


mov bh,Fdigit
sub bh,30h
mov ch,afd

add bl,bh
add bl,ch

mov al,bl
mov ah,00h
aaa

mov bx,ax
;mov bh, ah
;mov bl,al

mov dx, offset result
mov ah,09h
int 21h

;1st digit
mov Fdigit,bl
mov dl,Fdigit
add dl,30h
mov ah,02h
int 21h

;2nd digit
mov Sdigit,cl
mov dl,Sdigit
add dl,30h
mov ah,02h
int 21h
jmp DisplayMenu
ret



view_workshop:
; code to view workshop
mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset msg2
int 21h

mov bl,Sdigit
sub bl,30h
mov cl,wsd

add bl,cl

mov al,bl
mov ah,00h
aaa

mov cl,al
mov bl,ah

mov bh,Fdigit
sub bh,30h
mov ch,wfd

add bl,bh
add bl,ch

mov al,bl
mov ah,00h
aaa
mov bx,ax

;1st digit
mov Fdigit,bl
mov dl,Fdigit
add dl,30h
mov ah,02h
int 21h

;2nd digit
mov Sdigit,cl
mov dl,Sdigit
add dl,30h
mov ah,02h
int 21h
jmp DisplayMenu
ret


view_comp:
mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset msg
int 21h

mov bl,Sdigit 
sub bl,30h
mov cl,csd

add bl,cl

mov al,bl
mov ah,00h
aaa

mov cl,al
mov bl,ah


mov bh,Fdigit
sub bh,30h
mov ch,cfd

add bl,bh
add bl,ch

mov al,bl
mov ah,00h
aaa

mov bx,ax
;mov bh, ah
;mov bl,al

mov dx, offset result
mov ah,09h
int 21h

;1st digit
mov Fdigit,bl
mov dl,Fdigit
add dl,30h
mov ah,02h
int 21h


;2nd digit
mov Sdigit,cl
mov dl,Sdigit
add dl,30h
mov ah,02h
int 21h

jmp DisplayMenu
ret

reset:


    mov Fdigit,0
    mov Sdigit,0
    
mov dx, offset result
mov ah,09h
int 21h
    
    ;1st digit
mov Fdigit,0
mov dl,Fdigit
mov ah,02h
int 21h


;2nd digit
mov Sdigit,0
mov dl,Sdigit
mov ah,02h
int 21h
    
jmp DisplayMenu

ret



quit_program:
mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset Fdigit
int 21h
mov ah,4ch
int 21h

Main endp
End main
```

What i expect the code above to work properly but now i dont have any idea how to solve this issue.

Comment: You used `call` instead of `je`. Learn to use a debugger. Also, this is not 64 bit, it is 16 bit.

Comment: @Jester i did, but when i choose option 4, it will run the option 3 function

Comment: Yes, because you unconditionally `call view_comp` after `cmp al, '3'`.  That code then jumps back instead of returning, leaving a return address on the stack.  Also, there's no point in `cmp al, '4'` since you don't have any code to handle the case where the input wasn't 1..4.  After checking for 1, 2, or 3, the all other inputs can use the same path of execution, `'4'` isn't special.

Comment: i just found the solution  using ```.386``` to extend the use of ```je``` and thanks for your help @Jester and @Peter Corder

Comment: You don't need to have a `ret` directly after an unconditional `jmp`. The `jmp` will take place and the `ret` after it will never be run.

Answer (score 2):

A `cmp` by itself isn't enough to change the execution path of the program. The first two are correct, but the second two will execute regardless of the result of the compare above them. While the CPU has compared `al` to 3, it hasn't *done anything based on the result of that comparison.* Essentially, `cmp al, '3'` is the same as `sub al, '3'` in terms of how the `flags` register is affected, but the contents of `al` remain unchanged. For the first two cases, you've used `je` to branch based on the `flags`. As PeterCordes explained, you can actually optimize this a bit by rearranging your code to reduce branching. There's probably a better way than I've shown here, but it's just one example. (Depending on how much code you have under each label you might exceed the distance limit on `je` so keep that in mind.)

```
cmp al, '1'
je view_activites 
cmp al, '2'
je view_workshop
cmp al, '3' 
je view_comp

;else, reset

reset:
    mov Fdigit,0
    mov Sdigit,0
    ;rest of reset code goes here
    jmp DisplayMenu

view_activities:
    ; put your code here
    jmp DisplayMenu

view_workshop:
    ; put your code here
    jmp DisplayMenu

view_comp:
    ; put your code here
    jmp DisplayMenu

quit_program:
    ; put your code here
```